# Performance/profiling measurement in C

Tags: c, performance, profiling

I'm doing some prototyping work in C, and I want to compare how long a program takes to complete with various small modifications.

I've been using `clock`; from K&R:

> `clock` returns the processor time used by the program since the beginning of execution, or `-1` if unavailable.

This seems sensible to me, and has been giving results which broadly match my expectations. But is there something better to use to see what modifications improve/worsen the efficiency of my code?

Update: I'm interested in both Windows and Linux here; something that works on both would be ideal.

Update 2: I'm less interested in *profiling* a complex problem than total run time/clock cycles used for a simple program from start to finish—I already know which parts of my program are slow. `clock` appears to fit this bill, but I don't know how vulnerable it is to, for example, other processes running in the background and chewing up processor time.

Comment: I don't know of a profiler that works on more than one O/S. Either use more than one (for each O/S), or use one for one O/S and hope that the improvements which you make as a result of profiling on one platform will automatically be improvements on the other platform too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In POSIX (e.g. on Linux), you can use `gettimeofday()` to get higher-precision timing values (microseconds).

In Win32, `QueryPerformanceCounter()` is popular.

Beware of CPU clock-changing effects, if your CPU decides to clock down during the test, results may be skewed.

Answer (score 4):

Forget time() functions, what you need is:

**[Valgrind!](http://valgrind.org/)**

And KCachegrind is the best gui for examining callgrind profiling stats. In the past I have ported applications to linux *just* so I could use these tools for profiling.

Answer (score 3):

For a rough measurement of overall running time, there's `time ./myprog`.

But for *performance measurement*, you should be using a profiler. For GCC, there is [`gprof`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.37/gprof/index.html).

This is both assuming a Unix-ish environment. I'm sure there are similar tools for Windows, but I'm not familiar with them.

**Edit:** For clarification: I do advise *against* using any gettime() style functions in your code. Profilers have been developed over decades to do the job you are trying to do with five lines of code, and provide a much more powerful, versatile, valuable, and fool-proof way to find out where your code spends its cycles.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that timing programs, and finding things to optimize, are two different problems, and for both of them I personally prefer low-tech.

For timing, the trick is to make it take long enough by wrapping a loop around it. For example, if you iterate an operation 1000 times and time it with a stopwatch, then seconds become milliseconds when you remove the loop.

For finding things to optimize, there are pieces of code (terminal instructions and function calls) that are responsible for various fractions of the time. During that time, they are exposed on the stack. So you can wrap a loop around the program to make it take long enough, and then take [stackshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/1562802#1562802). The code to optimize will jump out at you.

Comment: +1 for looping to make the duration longer, and I wish I could add another +1 for the last paragraph.

Comment: @ChrisW: Biologists call this "amplifying the signal", when they make millions of copies of a piece of DNA so they can read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use POSIX functions, have a look at [`clock_gettime`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock_gettime.html).  I found [an example](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/) from a quick google search on how to use it.  To measure processor time taken by your program, you need to pass `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` as the first argument to `clock_gettime`, if your system supports it.  Since `clock_gettime` uses [`struct timespec`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/time.h.html), you can probably get useful nanosecond resolution.

As others have said, for any serious profiling work, you will need to use a dedicated profiler.