# Comparasion Time Complexity of Insertion Sort

Tags: java, c, algorithm, performance-testing

I've implemented insertion sort in C(Visual Studio) and Java(Eclipse) to analyse the time required for completion and to compare the difference in both the languages.

I tried to find out the worst case time required for the algorithm to complement.(Convert decreasing array to increasing one).

I run my code with samples of 10,000, 50,000 and 100,000 entries and the following were the observations:

```
In C:
10000: 0.172 seconds
50000: 3.874 seconds
100000: 15.384 seconds

whereas in Java
10000: 0.048 seconds
50000: 0.385 seconds
100000: 1.924 seconds
```

My code is normal insertion sort code. Nothing new in it. The time measured are only of insertion sort code and i/o operations are independent of it. e.g:

```
Input
Timer starts here
Insertion Sort
Timer ends
Summary(Time required and all)
```

I believed C was faster than Java but I couldn't justify this result..

EDIT: Here's the C code

```
void InsertionSort(int a[]) {
    int i;
    clock_t st, end;
    st = clock();
    for (i = 1; i < MAX; i++)   {
        int temp = a[i];
        int pos = i - 1;
        while(a[pos] > temp)    {
            a[pos + 1] = a[pos];
            pos--;
        }
        a[pos + 1] = temp;
    }
    end = clock();
    printf("\nSorting Completed. Time taken:%f", (double)(end - st) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

and Java Code:

```
public void Sort(int a[], int size) {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < size; i++)  {
            int temp = a[i];
            int pos = i - 1;
            while(pos >= 0 && a[pos] > temp)    {
                a[pos + 1] = a[pos];
                pos--;
            }

            a[pos + 1] = temp;
        }
}
```

Comment: did you try compiling the C code with -O3?

Comment: Exactly, use -O3 flag for compilation, and make sure you are in Release  mode.

Comment: Were you sorting the same size data-type in each case?

Comment: @Nobilis No never heard of it

Comment: @bugsbunny Okay, compile your code with the -O3 flag and compare the speeds again :)

Comment: If that doesn't work try including your insertion sort and setup code in the question.

Comment: It's probably because depending on the Array and the items, Java chooses the most efficient way to sort them, whereas C may be more straightforward.

Comment: Note in Visual Studio, this will be the `/O3` flag, I believe.  But there should be an "optimizations" setting in one of the build config tabs to control this.

Comment: @Fabinout - I was under the impression the OP has implemented insertion sort themselves.

Comment: @selig Well, that wasn't very clear anyway ;)

Comment: Have you can tried running the insertion sort function multiple time on same data set instead of running just once. I would suggest run multiple times on same data set to get average run time.

Comment: @praks411: Run-to-run discrepancies are unlikely to explain a 10-to-1 speed difference...

Comment: Is it possible your C-program compiled with Visual Studio also is compiled towards the MSIL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language If that is the case, you are comparing two implementations of virtual machines (Java virtual machine versus MSIL virtual machine)

Comment: Try to compile\run both codes on the Terminal instead of using IDE

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I altered the project properties and the program runs 4 times faster but still it is slow as compared to Java. Does by any chance JVM implements program in threads even if they are not implemented in program?

Comment: @Nobilis tried optimization but still it is slower to java

Comment: @bugsbunny Can you please post your C code?

Comment: @bugsbunny, why are you using `clock`? Did you try to profile the code?

Comment: @Nobilis I used clock to measure the time taken for the sorting process. I didn't try profiling.

Comment: @bugsbunny Well, profile the code and compare the times :) After a quick google search there seems to be a profiler available for Visual Studio (if that's what you're using). Consider this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx Other SO posters can weigh in if using clock is an effective way to profile the code but for C on Linux profiling is typically done using `gprof`

Comment: @bugsbunny Also consider this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055685/performance-profiling-measurement-in-c

Comment: In VS, are you compiling release or debug? Also, how are you measuring the time in java?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get jconsole to print the time so I used the crudest way to compare times (I used your insertion sort implementation) on Linux.

C (gcc is alised to `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -Waggregate-return -Wshadow`):

```
$ gcc -O3 insertion_sort.c 
$ date; ./a.out; date
Tue Jun 11 20:16:24 MYT 2013
Tue Jun 11 20:16:36 MYT 2013
```

Java:

```
$ javac Main.java
$ date; java Main; date
Tue Jun 11 20:19:11 MYT 2013
Tue Jun 11 20:19:32 MYT 2013
```

It's pretty evident that C outperforms Java, I used an array of size 150 000 and sorted in reverse. I've provided links to my code:

[C](http://codebin.org/view/1dbdabba)

[Java](http://codebin.org/view/72448b1c)

My recommendation is to set up a virtual machine running a Linux OS and to try it yourself (learning some Linux is incredibly useful not to mention that C programming is a breeze on it).

Comment: Ya I've got VMware and I tried it on Linux. C outperforms Java. Now I'm trying the profiler tool in Visual Studio. Still trying optimize code in VS. Thanks for the help. It was very useful.:)

Comment: No problem, I'm very surprised VS would compile C in such a manner, though -O3 makes a huge difference, without it, it took around 48 secs on my machine.